# Parse multiple line query to a single line query stored in a string in C++

Tags: c++, sql, database, string, parsing

I am very new to C++ and it is taking some time for me to implement things. 
My program should parse the input batch file (Example: input.SQL) given by the user 
using the command

> ./DBMS script=input.SQL (where DBMS is an executable file).

I am trying to store all the data to a string (SQL_Query). My code runs in such a way that, the queries are parsed and executed one at a time which should have semicolon separator at the end of each line. My code is getting a segmentation error when I tried to parse the input. The input file is in the following format.

```
CREATE TABLE T(K INT, A INT, C CHAR(1), PRIMARY KEY(K));<br/>
INSERT INTO T VALUES(1,1,'A');<br/>
SELECT K,C<br/>
FROM T<br/>
WHERE A=1;<br/>
SELECT *<br/>
FROM (SELECT I,D FROM S WHERE B=3)Z1;<br/>
SELECT X.K,Y.C,X.C<br/>
FROM (SELECT * FROM T WHERE C='A') X<br/>
JOIN (SELECT K, C FROM Z)Y ON Y.K=X.K;<br/>
SELECT X1.K, Y1.C, X1.C<br/>
FROM (SELECT T.K,T.C FROM T JOIN Z ON T.K=Z.K WHERE T.C='A') X1<br/>
JOIN (SELECT Z.K,Z.C FROM Z)Y1 ON Y1.K=X1.K;
```

I need to get this multiple line query to a single line so that my program works. I have searched regarding this but did not find something helpful.

I tried doing it in this way but could not succeed.

```
for(int index = 0; index < SQL_Query.size(); index++){
    if (SQL_Query.at(index) == ';'){
      SQL_Query += " " + SQL_Query;
      index++;
    }
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: You are parsing the same string you are building !

Comment: Yes. I want to get the string to the format my code runs.